# Escape dot on jQuery XML select

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have an XML :

```
<computers>
  <computer>
    <description>Description</description>
    <computer.always></computer.always>
  </computer>
</computers>
```

So i want to access the computer.always element, so I use this :

```
$(xml).find('computer ' + "computer.always".replace(/\./g,'\\\\.'))
```

And the element is not found. 
( I wrote "computer.always".replace(/./g,'\\.') because "computer.always" can be a variable and i need to make this selector dynamic. )

The weird thing is :

**When I do :**

```
$(xml).find('computer computer\\.always') // Element found
```

**My element is find.**

But when I use the result of "computer.always".replace(/./g,'\\.'), it fails.

```
"computer.always".replace(/\./g,'\\\\.') // return "computer computer\\.always" in the console
 $(xml).find("computer.always".replace(/\./g,'\\\\.')) => []
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, my error was to use double \, so the console use it to echo but not my code. My solution was to use :

```
$(xml).find("computer.always".replace(/\./g,'\\.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

"computer.always".replace(/./g,'\\.') is not working because you just need "computer\.always".

So if instead you do it like this, it should work.

`$(xml).find( "computer " + "computer.always".replace(/./g,'\\.') )`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry about that, stackoverflow played a trick on me, since then '\\.' was showing only '\.', but it seems like you already found the solution. I fixed it thought.